# P is a point inside a circle and A is a point on the circumference.Find the radius of the circle.

Tags: circles

P is a point inside a circle and A is a point on the circumference. The **minimum** distance between A and P is 2 cm and the **maximum** distance between A and P is 8 cm. Find the **radius** of the circle.
I think the radius must be greater than 4 cm. But next how to proceed ??

Comment: Is there a rule as to how $P$ is chosen other than it being inside the circle? If not, shouldn't the minimum distance between $A$ and $P$ be $0$? What makes you think the radius is $>4$?

Comment: Are you familiar with triangular inequality?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Minimum AP=2 cm is given in the question. Since P is inside a circle and maximum AP=8 cm, so the diameter is greater than 8 cm and therefore, radius > 4 cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triangular inequality to show that the minimum and maximum distances are attained when the point $A$ is on the diameter passing through $P$ (see Figure in the bottom).

For example,
$$A'P+OP = r,$$
where $r$ is the circle radius, and, by triangular inequality on triangle $AOP$,
$$AP+OP \geq r,$$
so that 
$$AP \geq A'P.$$
So no matter where you take $A$ the distance from $P$ will be greater than that of $A'$ from $P$. Thus
$$A'P=2\ \mbox{cm}.$$
Similarly, you can express $A''P$ as
$$A''P = r + OP,$$
whereas, again for triangular inequality on $AOP$,
$$AP \leq r + OP,$$
which yields
$$ AP \leq A''P.$$
In conclusion $A''P = 8$ cm and the radius is $r = \frac{A'P + A''P}{2}=5$ cm.

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

Comment: Ok. then while doing same with A'',, will i take triangle AOA'' ?? Is AP=2 cm ??

Comment: @SubhamSen: $AP$ is greater than $A'P$, as we just demonstrated, right? Since $2$ cm is the minimum distance, then which segment is $2$ cm long? For the other question: try expressing $A''P$ in terms of the radius.

Comment: @SubhamSen added the conclusion in the text.

Comment: a> I couldn't get how A'P=2 cm and A''P=8 cm ??

Comment: b> Why are you saying, " no matter where you take A the distance from P will be greater than that of A' " ??

Comment: @SubhamSen question b> must be dealt first. What I meant is that if the point $A$ is not taken on the diameter passing through point $P$, then its distance from $P$ will be greater than *the distance of $A'$ from $P$*, $A'$ being exactly the point intersected on the circle by the diameter passing through $P$. And this is just a rephrasing of what was demonstrated via triangular inequality.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Matteo ...

Answer (score 0):

The minimum distance from the point on the circumference will be at a right angle to the edge of the circle and the maximum distance will pass through the center point and also be at a right angle. Adding to two distances will make the diameter of the circle: $8+2 = 10$cm, therefore the radius is $5$ cm.